# Developing intuition about free groups / the universal property

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'd like to check my intuition here since my chapter on free groups had my brain in a knot for a little while.

I know a free group is a group basically defined by all the reduced words of elements found in some indexing set, and that we can define homomorphisms from every free group into any group simply by defining where the generators of the free group are sent.

Am I right in describing this intuition: The preimage of the homomorphism, in the free group, could be considered to describe the order we apply different elements (images of the generators of the free group) in the original group, without keeping track of where we end up. The image under the homomorphism would be the ending "location," effectively "resolving" the sequence of "actions" described by the element of the free group.

So, in one example of this, I am thinking of the free group generated by moveup/movedown and moveleft/moveright, with rank 2, and then the same group action on the set of a 3x3 grid "Snake-Style" aka Z_3 x Z_3, and the homomorphism from the free group (Left - Down - Down - Down) would map to simply moving Left on the grid if you follow the mapping you'd expect.

But I could have decided to have "moveup" map to "move up" and "move left" also map to "move up" and then left-down-down-down would, in the homomorphism, simply move me up once and then down 3 times, effectively moving me down two times (which may have resulted in a looparound).

Is this a reasonable understanding of the universal property?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are describing in terms of preimages, but here is how I understand the universal property: a group is free on a set precisely if homomorphisms out of it are uniquely determined by the images of the elements in the set. (Determined because the set-theoretic map readily extends to a group homomorphism on the free group essentially by definition of the latter, and uniquely because this definition is forced by the requirement of being a homomorphism.)

Comment: This is exactly analogous to the intuition regarding the statement "linear transformations are uniquely determined by their action on a basis" in linear algebra. In fact, both are essentially the same statement: free groups are free objects in the category of groups, and vector spaces are free objects in the category of vector spaces.

Comment: I actually did write the statement in your second comment beneath the theorem in my notes, before you mentioned it. But I was seeking a way to understand the distinction in arbitrary groups. The preimage in this case is the string, ie left down down down, and the image is the resulting group member if you had followed the string of actions applied to the identity in the image group.

Comment: In other words, I was seeking intuition as to what such a homomorphism could even *mean* in some context. The existence and uniqueness property was not really my problem.

Comment: I don't understand how your intuition "distinguishes" between a free group and any other group. Any group homomorphism may be described by its action on generators, as any group element may be written as a "string" of generators.

Comment: In a free group the element itself is the string of generators entirely unsimplified according to any other relation. The string could be seen as a sequence of instructions. After the homomorphism the string is effectively "simplified" according to the relations of the group in its image. That's the case in other groups too, but the free group has as its elements every possible sequence of actions in the image group, whereas in other groups would have restrictions on which sequences of actions are equivalent.

Comment: This "explains" why the free group has homomorphisms to any group, whereas not-free groups might have no such homomorphism.

Comment: That's right: a free group has "the most" homomorphisms to any other group, because relations are obstructions to defining homomorphisms, and a free group has none. Said differently: any group $G$ is a quotient $F/R$ of a free group $F$ by some relations $R$, and a homomorphism $\phi:F \to H$ to any other group descends to the quotient $G$ if and only if the relations $R$ get killed by the homomorphism (i.e. belong to $\ker \phi$).

Comment: Ha, thanks, I am aware and fixed it. I've been swapping back and forth between topology and algebra; forgive my fingers' muscle memory :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct. For further intuition, think about the free group $F_2$ on two generators $a$ and $b$ as the set of all grid paths on $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ starting at $(0,0)$ and moving between horizontally or vertically adjacent vertices without immediate backtracking. The paths $(0,0)\to (0,1)\to(1,1)$ and $(0,0)\to (1,0)\to(1,1)$ are considered distinct. Paths are added similarly as vectors (with potential cancelling). Now we map $(F_2,\text{path addition})$ to $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z},+)$ by looking only at the endpoint of such a path. We loose the information on the exact journey of the path, i.e., the order in which the moves occurred, but we do know the net amount of horizontally and vertically moves. This is equivalent to introducing the relation $ab=ba$ into the free group. $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ has in fact the presentation $\left<a,b\;|\;ab=ba\right>.$

Think of the [Cayley graph of $F_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:F2_Cayley_Graph.png) as representing all of these paths, and think how this is mapped to the rectangular grid.

Comment: Thanks! I was somewhat confused when some online lectures were describing the free abelian group with rank 2 as isomorphic to Z⊕Z -- I thought this was isomorphic to ZxZ, so why would someone choose to represent it as Z⊕Z in this case?

Comment: @OpalE Because Abelian groups are described using additive notation most of the time, the symbol $\oplus$ is preferred. It doesn't matter, as *finite* direct sums and direct products coincide.